# Woo-commerce produce invoice receipt can not show title correctly in multi-language

Tags: html, woocommerce

with the help of Qtranslate, woo-commerce product can have multi-lang

it looks fine on website where product in English called product A in Chinese called 产品A

however， in invoice the title looks weird

In logic, invoice should say Product A 
Or  产品A depends on you are in CHINESE, or English version website

however, in reality, for example, if you are in English version buying product A. invoice will appear:

[:en]Product A [:zh]产品A [:]
Item# XC9T

see? it not only include both Chinese and English title, but also give you a weird tag [:en],[:zh]

So how to make my invoice look normal

Comment: This might be a question that should be asked at: https://woocommerce.com/contact-us/

Comment: Answer is here: https://github.com/qTranslate-Team/woocommerce-qtranslate-x/issues/49

Answer (score 0):

The question is solved
Answer is here:

github.com/qTranslate-Team/woocommerce-qtranslate-x/issues/49